# Interacting with a SwiftUI view below a UIKit PKCanvasView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, uiviewrepresentable

I have a view Structure as follows:

```
ZStack {
    UIKitView //PKCanvasView
        .zIndex(1)
    SwiftUIView //SwiftUI view which has a gesture recogniser 
        .zIndex(0)
}
```

I wanted to know what the best way was to allow **simultaneous** interaction to the `SwiftUI` view below the `UIKit` view.

This would work best if the `SwiftUI` view had a `higher priority gesture` over the UIKit view on top.

My UIKit representable view is as follows:

```
struct CanvasView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var canvasView: PKCanvasView
    @Binding var isFirstResponder: Bool
    
    @State var toolPicker = PKToolPicker()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKCanvasView {
        
        canvasView.drawingPolicy = .pencilOnly
        canvasView.backgroundColor = .clear
        canvasView.isOpaque = false
        canvasView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        canvasView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
        
        
        toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: canvasView)
        toolPicker.addObserver(canvasView)
        //canvasView.becomeFirstResponder()
        
        return canvasView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PKCanvasView, context: Context) {
        if isFirstResponder != uiView.isFirstResponder {
           if isFirstResponder {
               uiView.becomeFirstResponder() 
           } else {
               uiView.resignFirstResponder()
           }
       }
    }
    
}
```

Ideally I would like to handle the layering of views in `SwiftUI` as in reality a have multiple `SwiftUI` views below the canvas view which when held & dragged (that is the compound gesture I am applying to them) should appear above it. (This is achieved using dynamic `zIndex`s). I'm not comfortable enough with `UIKit` to know how to do this there with subviews and a `UIViewRepresentable` structure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You keep saying the SwiftUI view is "below" the UIKit view, but it seems like that's not the case. I mean, the SwiftUI view is *above* the UIKit view (closer to the user), right? Anyway, if I understand you, you want to have gestures recognized by both views. What if you just put `onTapGesture` on *both* views? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Why are you trying to capture the gesture in SwiftUI, are you trying to do something like a cursor? Just so I understand the problem better.

Comment: @CasperZandbergen well I’m trying to allow the user to draw on the PKCancasView view only when using the Apple Pencil and simultaneously drag, and interact with SwiftUI views below the canvas view when using their finger. At the moment I can’t figure out how to allow the user to interact with views below the UIViewRepresentable. No touches go through

Comment: @santi.gs I don't know much about PencilKit, but what if on the `CanvasView` you use `.allowsHitTesting(_:)` depending on if they have a pencil vs finger? Set to `true` when using a pencil, and `false` when using their finger. That means that when using their finger, touches will pass through to the back view. Make sure this canvas is the top view: `ZStack { SwiftUIView(...)  \n  CanvasView(...) }`. From your description, it doesn't sound like you need to be able to receive touches on **both simultaneously**. Just be able to switch between.

Comment: @George_E. I tried this but as soon as allowsHitTesting is toggled to false, the PKCanvasView can no longer be interacted with and so I can no longer differentiate between pencil and finger touches to toggle again. If only there was a way to differentiate between touch types in SwiftUI... thanks anyway

Comment: @santi.gs It's really unfortunate that I would like to give this question a go and try and find a solution, but the Xcode simulator doesn't support a virtual Apple Pencil (and I don't have one). In your question you need to differentiate between a tap and drawing with the pencil, so I can't just change the `drawingPolicy` :/